# How to set a button an image in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uibutton, uiimage

Hello I am struggling with setting an image to a button when it is pressed, the code will only allow me to pass a `UIImage` through but I am unsure how to get a `UIImage` as the only image display I can use is a `UIImageView` therefor I am unable to change the image which is vital for my app. here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func Play(sender: AnyObject) {
        let random: Int = Int(arc4random() % 2)

        if random == 1 {
            player1Turn = true
        }else{
            player1Turn = false
        }
    }

    @IBAction func CenterButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        //if player1Turn == true{
            CenterButton.backgroundColor = nil
            CenterButton.setImage(Cross, forState: .Normal)
        //}else{
           // CenterButton.backgroundColor = nil
            //CenterButton.setImage(Nort, forState: .Normal)
        //}
    }

    @IBAction func LeftCenterButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    }

    @IBAction func CenterRightButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    }

    @IBAction func BottomRightButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    }

    @IBAction func BottomLeftButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    }

    @IBAction func BottomCenterbutton(sender: AnyObject) {
    }

    @IBAction func TopLeftButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    }

    @IBAction func TopCenterButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    }

    @IBAction func TopRightButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var BottomCenterbutton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var GameView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var PlayerOneLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var CenterButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var TopLeftButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var LeftCenterButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var TopCenterButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var BottomLeftButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var BottomRightButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var CenterRightButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var TopRightButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Play: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Board: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Nort: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Cross: UIImage!
    var player1Turn: Bool?
```

If you are able to see any other mistake in my code I would be very grateful with the advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a button an image using `setImage(named, forState)` like this:

```
CenterButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Cross"), forState: .Normal)
```

Which will assign an image named `Cross` to the `CenterButton`.